# Go - use of internal package [...] not allowed

Tags: windows, package, maven-plugin, go-build, stellar

I tried to clone and build the project from the [stellar bridge-server github repository](https://github.com/stellar/bridge-server). After quite a lot of steps I am facing following errors:

> [ERROR] github.com\stellar\go\services\bridge\internal\handlers\main.go:8:2: use of internal package github.com/stellar/go/services/bridge/internal/db not allowed
>   [ERROR] github.com\stellar\go\services\bridge\internal\handlers\main.go:9:2: use of internal package github.com/stellar/go/services/bridge/internal/listener not allowed
>   [ERROR] github.com\stellar\go\services\bridge\internal\handlers\main.go:10:2: use of internal package github.com/stellar/go/services/bridge/internal/submitter not allowed
>
> *( ... many more issues of same format ... )*

I imported the dependencies and different packages but when I try to compile and install it I get this errors. I moved some folders to their upper folder to have a same directory as in repo wished but the errors are still the same.

I'm pretty confused and do not understand this problem. I'm totaly new in packaging directory system.

What is the problem here and what should I do?

Thank you for your help.